# What kind of apparatus is Bane's mask?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

During the course of the film, it is explained that Bane has to wear his mask in order to keep his pain level down to a bare minimum.

During the final fight, we see Batman start to disable this device by disconnecting some of the *piping* on it.

What kind of device is this exactly and is there a real-world equivalent that causes the same effects?

Comment: Its very different from the one they showed in Arkham city and comics.

Comment: The best part is that when the League of Shadows rescue Bane from the prison, he's got a simple cloth covering his mouth and chin. I guess the debilitating pain only occurs above ground. :P

Comment: CIA Agent: "If I take that off, will you die?" Bane: "It will be extremely painful..." CIA Agent: "You're a big guy" Bane: "For you."

Comment: Here's a humorous [take](http://www.pidjin.net/2013/03/07/in-vader/). Note the Do Not Wash sticker ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think I really answered the original question.
Regarding real-life variations on Bane's mask, the following snippet can be found on wikipedia:

*Other gases or vapors which produce general anesthesia by inhalation include nitrous oxide, cyclopropane and xenon. These are stored in gas cylinders and administered using flow meters, rather than vaporizers*

I found a couple of real world images that struck a chord - the first looks like the masks worn in Batman Begins (in shape only, not in function)

[image]

and the second image is of a concept mask for firefighters which could be attached to gas cylinders. I have to say though, that no cylinders were apparent on Bane's costume.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a film after all, so let's just run with it, maybe it's a refill which he changes every do often, in the comic he has "venom" pumped into him every 12 hours, so they might have taken that idea, but instead of venom decided to take a more realistic approach and give him anathsetic.

Also at the beginning of the movie in the plane, he is asked if he will die if the mask is removed, his reply is "it would be extremely painful, for you."

Comment: The exact line is Mercenary: "What happens if I remove that mask"  Bane: "It would be very painful" (mercenary laughs) Bane: "For you..."

Comment: Correction: The exact lines are Mercenary: "What happens if I remove that mask" Bane: "It would be very painful" (mercenary laughs) Mercenary: "You're a big guy" Bane: "For you..."

Comment: took three tries but eventually we nailed it! ;)

Comment: Actually it was the CIA Agent played by Aidan Gillen (of Game of Thrones fame) who said those lines not one of the mercenaries.